# Does asymptotic normality of the likelihood function follow from the central limit theorem?

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, central-limit-theorem, asymptotics

In the book *Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering* it is said that the likelihood function tends to a Gaussian (centred on the maximum-likelihood estimate) in the large sample limit. The way it is phrased makes it seem like they are saying this is due to the central limit theorem, but I am struggling to see how it is relevant. It relies on the random variable being a sum of a sequence of other random variables, which I don't think is the case here.

I believe this is often misunderstood, for example in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/394768/how-is-it-possible-for-both-the-likelihood-and-log-likelihood-to-be-asymptotical), which I have several problems with. The arguments use the central limit theorem to find the distribution of the likelihood and show that it is asymptotically normal. However, we are not interested in its *distribution* as a random variable; we instead care about its *functional form* as the parameters are varied for given observed sample values.

As an example of what I mean, suppose we draw $n$ sample values $x_i$ from a distribution $P(x|\tau)=(1/\tau)\exp(-x/\tau)$. The likelihood function is then $$L(\boldsymbol{x};\tau)=P(x_1|\tau)P(x_2|\tau)\dots P(x_n|\tau)=\frac{1}{\tau^n}\exp{\left[-\frac{\sum_i x_i}{\tau}\right]}.$$
Suppose we now evaluate this using the observed values of $x_i$ and consider it as a function of $\tau$. In general this will obviously be different every time, but the book says that in the limit $n\to\infty$, the function tends to a Gaussian with peak centred on the maximum likelihood estimate $\hat{\tau}$ and width inversely proportional $\sqrt{n}$. Why should we expect this to be the case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof that ML Estimator is asymptotically Normal](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/309469/proof-that-ml-estimator-is-asymptotically-normal)

Comment: I think this is different, as it is the maximum likelihood estimator rather than the likelihood function

Comment: it's related to what may be called Bayesian central limit theorem.

Comment: The *log* likelihood (not the likelihood itself!) is a sum of *iid* random variables.  Throw in the usual technical requirements (*e.g.*, finite variances) and *QED.*

Comment: If the log-likelihood is a sum of iid random variables, this doesn't say anything about its functional form right? CLT says that the distribution of the sum is Gaussian, not the sum itself.

Comment: The distribution of a properly-normalized sum will approach a Gaussian (with a few extra conditions...) but the distribution of the sum is not itself Gaussian (unless the variables being summed are all Gaussian.)

Comment: I'm sorry, but the phrase "distribution of the sum is Gaussian, not the sum itself" makes no sense to me: in what sense is a sum of random variables "Gaussian" if not in terms of its distribution??  Regardless, the CLT does not assert any distribution of any sum is Gaussian: it's a limiting statement about distributions of sums.  See [our posts on the CLT](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=central+limit+theorem+score%3A25+is%3Aanswer) for more about that. We care *very much* about the distribution of the log likelihood because that tells us how certain we can be about estimates.

Comment: The point (which I have tried to make clear in my edit) is that we are considering the random variables to be fixed (e.g. we take a random sample and evaluate the sum once) and then consider the functional form as the parameter is varied, which should be Gaussian.

Comment: Could you provide an example of a model in which the data remain fixed and the number of parameters increases without limit?  Exactly how do the parameters change?  Certainly there will be no general theorem about what such a model looks like or what its asymptotic behavior is!  This sounds rather like a misinterpretation of the phrase "large sample limit," which refers to a situation in which an arbitrarily large sample from a *fixed* distribution can be obtained (and has nothing to do with parameters at all).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the number of parameters is fixed, but the number of sample points increases. I have given an example in the question.

Comment: Once again: this is the CLT in action.  Each $x_i$ is a random variable and therefore your *log* likelihood is proportional to a sum of *iid* random variables.  Because the common variance of the $x_i$ is finite, the distribution of the standardized log likelihood converges to that of the standard Normal distribution.

Comment: @whuber for a given $\theta$ we can consider the log likelihood as a variable that is a sum $$Y(\theta) = \log \mathcal{L}(\theta; \textbf{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log \mathcal{l}(\theta; x_i) $$ and based on the principle of the CLT we can say that for a fixed $\theta$ the distribution of $Y(\theta)$ will approximate a normal distribution, but this doesn't automatically mean that the shape of the function $Y(\theta)$ has the shape of a normal distribution. In fact the log likelihood approaches a quadratic curve.

Comment: @Sextus Of course -- and evidently that's how the question was intended to be interpreted.  But the question is ambiguous and I was addressing a *different* interpretation; namely, that of the limiting distribution of the log likelihood.

Comment: @whuber your questioning can be at some times Socratic while people don't know that it is intended that way. ;-)

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus That wasn't the intention here: I simply did not conceive of the alternative interpretation this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the question here is why/whether the loglikelihood function is asymptotically locally a parabola with its maximum at $\hat\theta$ (and so the likelihood function is locally $\exp(-(\theta-\hat\theta)^2/2)$.Basically, it's just Taylor series: any smooth function is locally a parabola, and any smooth function with zero derivative at a point is locally a parabola with a max or min at that point.  It isn't *quite* just Taylor series -- we do need the Law of Large Numbers and also the rate of convergence of an average to its expected value to be sure that the terms in the Taylor expansion are of the sizes we need them to be.

In this case (and relevant other cases) the log-likelihood function is smooth. By the definition of the MLE, the loglikelihood has a maximum at $\hat\theta$ and the derivative is zero at $\hat\theta$.  Therefore,
$$\ell(\theta)=\ell(\hat\theta) + 0\times (\theta-\hat\theta) + \ell''(\hat\theta)(\theta-\hat\theta)^2 +\text{remainder}$$
Since the derivatives of $\ell$ are proportional to $n$, we need $\theta-\hat\theta= O_p(n^{-1/2}$ to keep the remainder small, but that's the range we're interested in.  On that range,
$\ell(\hat\theta)-\ell(\theta)$ is asymptotically a parabola centered at $\hat\theta$, so $\exp(\ell(\theta))$ is asymptotically the same shape as a Gaussian likelihood function.

Comment: Great, thanks. So, am I right in saying that this seems quite different to the central limit theorem?

Comment: Yes, it does seem quite different.